# Python request.post gives 500 response

Tags: python, json, rest

For one of my post requests, I get a 500 response every time I try to run it. When I copy and paste the details in postman, it works fine every time. The python post works fine for other requests that I run, but this one fails every time and I can't work out why.

Has anyone come across this problem before, or can anyone see something that I've done wrong?

```
json_body = '{"overrides": [], "id": 0, "name": "Rate Sheet 12", "resellerId": 2000001, "currency": "ZAR", "markup": {"id": 0, "method": "Percentage", "operand": 3}, "totalLinkedBands": 0, "totalLinkedAccounts": 0}'
token = 'JWT eyJ0eXA...s'
url = 'http://app01:8084//PriceScheme/CreatePriceScheme'
r = requests.post(url, json.loads(json_body), headers={'Authorization': token})
```

In Postman it looks as follows:

```
(POST) http://app01:8084//PriceScheme/CreatePriceScheme
Content-Type - application/json
Authorization - JWT eyJ...

{"overrides": [], "name": "Rate Sheet 1", "currency": "ZAR", "totalLinkedAccounts": 0, "totalLinkedBands": 1, "id": 1, "markup": {"method": "Percentage", "operand": 3.0, "id": 0}, "resellerId": "2009340"}
```

Comment: Include the Postman Code in your question

Comment: Out of interest - the double '/' you have after the port number. Is that a typo?

Comment: A 500 is a internal server error. The examples you give for Python and Postman don't have the same payload (e.g. `id` is not the same), this could be the reason for one working and the other not. Please test it with exactly the same request and update the question. Also if you have access to the webserver logs you should see what is going wrong, as it's an internal server error.

Comment: In the one case "operand" is 3.0, in the other 3 - could it be a parsing issue server side perhaps?

Comment: postman works in different manner than `request.post`, how payload processed by postman is different than `request` before API hit. Assign `json_body` as plain json and not in single quotes when passing via `request`.This would be happening due to parsing issue. Also, in you API, add a `pdb` and check if the call is reaching the `view` or it is breaking at `apache` / `nginx` level itself!

Answer (score 2):

try as blew

```
requests.post(url, json = json_body, headers={'Authorization': token})
```

In Postman , auto using Content-Type - application/json

If using request post json data , should using json=data

Comment: I meet a similar problem , and using "json = json_body" fix the problem.

Comment: Can you try and expand your answer, that would probably help the OP and others to identify the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

`json_body='{"parametername":Value}'
resp = requests.post(URL, json_body, auth=('username', 'Pass'))`

Solved the issue in my case